# Warning with NO consequences: postfix/trivial-rewrite[]: warning: relay_domains lookup failure

Tags: mysql, postfix, mail-server

I get the below warning in the mail log file.

```
postfix/trivial-rewrite[]: warning: relay_domains lookup failure
```

The mail server is working well without any issues. What can this error mean?

Running the test below produces the required output.

```
postmap -q "example.org" mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf
```

Running with verbose confirms again that the query is successful and reading the correct table

```
postmap -v -q "example.org" mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf
```